# How to move from URL to URL in Java (Re-use reader-object?)

Tags: java

Sorry for the very basic question, I am new to Java.
To get data from an URL I use code like this

```
URL url = new URL(BaseURL+"login?name=foo");
URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
  ...
```

That works perfectly fine. When I now want to continue and send the next command to the server (like ".../getStatus"), do I need to create these objects over and over again, or is there a smarter way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `openConnection` again in order to get a new `URLConnection`. The HttpURLConnection does internal caching, though, so if the HTTP-server supports `Connection: keep-alive` the underlying connection to the server will be reused so it's not that bad as it originally might look. It's just hidden from you.

Comment: I can't pass the new URL to openConnection, so does that mean I have to create a new URL object and all the other associated readers etc. ? In this sample I log on via http://test.com/login?name=foo and then continue with http://test.com/GetInfo. Do I first create a URL+readers for the login request and then another URL+readers for the GetInfo-Request?

Comment: Yes. You also have to set Cookies as Request Headers if the server returns and relies on one. Alternatively you might use libraries that offer you an HTTP-Client that handles that for you. Apache Commons HTTP Client is an often used one for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the Apache HttpComponents (HttpClient) and it still requires a lot of code. As I don't need cookie-handling (it's only a simple RESTful server giving json-blocks as responses) I'm going for a very simple solution:

```
public static String readStringFromURL(String requestURL) throws IOException
{
   URL u = new URL(requestURL);
   try (InputStream in = u.openStream()) {
       return new String(in.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   }
}
```

For me that looks like a perfect solution, but as mentioned, I am new to Java and open (and thankful) for hints...